# amazon iam get inline policy statement in boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I'am using boto3 `list_role_policies` to get all inline policies but I'm getting only PolicyNames.  I would like to obtain the json statement as well.

Something like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "mobileanalytics:PutEvents",
                "cognito-sync:*",
                "cognito-identity:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Please, remember I don't want **managed policies, only Inline**.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Okay, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`iam.Role.policies`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#role) to iterate all inline policies for a specific role. You will get iterable of [`iam.RolePolicy`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#rolepolicy) instances which have `policy_document` attribute with policy JSON.

```
import boto3

iam = boto3.resource('iam')

role_name = 'RoleName'
role = iam.Role(role_name)
for policy in role.policies.all():
    print(policy.name)
    print(policy.policy_document)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the result of `list_role_policies()` to call [`get_role_policy()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.get_role_policy) on each of the policy names returned:

> Retrieves the specified inline policy document that is embedded with the specified IAM role.

```py
response = client.get_role_policy(
    RoleName='string',
    PolicyName='string'
)
```